# In python, what exactly is going on in the background such that "x = 1j" works, but "x = 1*j" throws an error?

Tags: python, built-in

Specifically, if I wanted to define an object, say z, such that

```
x = 1z
```

worked but

```
x = 1*z
```

<s>failed</s> threw an error, how would I define such an object?

I don't think it involves overloading the multiplying operator.

Comment: It's generally better to maintain consistent, standard syntax. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What do you mean x=1z worked?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't want to do this. I'm just curious if the ability to do this reveals anything about what's going on in the background. For example, the first time I saw numpy lists allow scalar multiplication, digging around led me to operator overloading, something I wasn't aware of before that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1j`, works because it's a [literal for a Complex Number](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals) (you mentioned `1j` in your question title). Kind of like `[]` is a literal for a list.

Here's the relevant excerpt from the Python docs / spec:

> Imaginary literals are described by the following lexical definitions:
>
> `imagnumber ::=  (floatnumber | intpart) ("j" | "J")`
>
> An imaginary
>   literal yields a complex number with a real part of 0.0. Complex
>   numbers are represented as a pair of floating point numbers and have
>   the same restrictions on their range. To create a complex number with
>   a nonzero real part, add a floating point number to it, e.g., `(3+4j)`.

In other words, `1j` is a special case, and there's nothing you can do to make `1z` work like `1j` does. `1z` is a `SyntaxError`, and that's it (as far as Python is concerned, that is).

Comment: "1z is a SyntaxError, and that's it". OK, I suspected as much. Thank you for clarifying that. Also, I tried to tag this with "complex" or "imaginary", but SO wouldn't let me because my reputation isn't high enough.